# A question on two polynomial ideals generated by the same polynomials have the same generator

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Here is the statement I want to prove:

> Let $K$ be a subfield of $F$, and $f,g\in{K[x]}$. Let $M_K=fK[x]+gK[x]$ and $M_F=fF[x]+gF[x]$. Show that $M_K$ and $M_F$ have the same monic generator.

My argument is the following: Suppose that $M_K=dK[x]$, then d is the unique and monic generator of $M_K$. Suppose $q\in{M_K}$, then there exists $q_1,q_2\in{K[x]}$ such that $q=fq_1+gq_2$ and there exists $q_3\in{K[x]}$ such that $q=dq_3$. So, $dq_3=fq_1+gq_2$. Also, since $q_1,q_2,q_3\in{K[x]}$, we have $q_1,q_2,q_3\in{F[x]}$. Thus, $fq_1+gq_2\in{M_F}$, i.e, $dq_3\in{M_F}$. I claim that since $q_3$ is an arbitrary polynomial in $F[x]$, it follows that $M_F=dF[x]$. Hence, d is also the unique and monic generator of $M_F$.

It seems logical but since I started with an assumption q belonging to $M_K$, I could not be sure. Is a converse implication needed, or is the idea completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is that both ideals are generated by the monic greatest common divisor of $f$ and $g$. and this is the same over all fields containing the coefficients of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Indeed. The Euclidean algorithm you use to calculate $d$ out of $f$ and $g$ doesn't "know" whether you are working in the field $K$ or in $F$, as all the calculations are done effectively in $K$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop, thanks for clarifying. That was my point, the algorithm only depends on the coefficients of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: So, the problem arises from the statement "since $q_1,q_2,q_3\in{K[x]}$, we have $q_1,q_2,q_3\in{F[x]}$", because it is possible that all the coefficients of $q_1,q_2,q_3$ are in the field $K$?

Comment: Yes, the monic generator is a linear combination with coefficients in $K[x]$ of the two polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d$ be the monic greatest common divisor of $f$ and $g$. So, $M_K=dK[x]$. Since $d\in{M_K}$, there exists $q_1,q_2\in{K[x]}$ such that $d=fq_1+gq_2$.

Now let $r$ be an arbitrary polynomial over the field $F$. Consider $dr=(fq_1+gq_2)r$, so $dr=fq_1r+gq_2r$, where $q_1r$ and $q_2r$ are polynomials over $F$. By the definition of the ideal $M_F$, we have $dr\in{M_F}$. We showed that multiplication of any polynomial over $F$ with $d$ belongs to $M_F$. Hence, $M_F=dF[x]$.